# Test system: checking if an answer is correct

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a test system that is driven by Wordpress where each answer is input with a true/false text box to say whether it's the correct answer of not.

I've created a loop that outputs the answers with a checkbox next to it:

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('answer_options')): ?>
<?php while(has_sub_field('answer_options')): ?>
<p class="contact-form">
  <input style="width: 20px;" type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>" />
  <?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>
</p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I add code to that to include whether the answer is the correct one? I can do a conditional statement like the following to check which answer is correct but how can I incorporate that with the code above?

It needs to check which is the correct answer and also whether the user has ticked the correct/incorrect checkbox.

```
if( get_sub_field('correct') )
{
    echo "do something";
}
else
{
    echo "do something else";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following:

```
<?php 
if( is_array( $_POST['CheckboxGroup'.$counter] ) ) {                                    
    foreach($_POST['CheckboxGroup'.$counter]  as  $value[$counter])  { 

        if ($answer == $value[$counter]) { ?>

    <p><?php $score++;echo $value[$counter]; ?></p><br />           
    <?php   }


}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check a user's input directly with php like this.

If you're outputting a form generated by html, it will need to be completed, and then submitted back to the web server.

You can check the answers when they submit the form. It sounds like you want to keep the same form and just mark questions as correct/incorrect.

Comment: I have got a submit button at the end. So if I can somehow check what the user has checked against the answer that was correct?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with WP, but I would imagine you could check $_POST['CheckboxGroup'.$i'] over a loop to determine answers for each question.